# How can I exclude links that have certain classes from an .on('click'

Tags: jquery

I have the following set up:

```
$("#content-button-panel")
       .on('click', 'a:not(".folder")', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var $link = $(this);
           ServerFunctions.getContentAjax($link);
       });
```

I alread exclude any link with a class of "folder". How can I also make 
it that the following links that have a class starting with "title-..." are excluded?

```
<a class="title-x">xx</a>
<a class="title-123243234">yyy</a>
<a class="title-sadfdsaf">zzz</a>
```

Comment: "following links" - is that (a) "following" as in "listed below in the question", or (b) "following" as in "siblings links below $link"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple selector this will exclude both anchor tag elements

```
    $("#content-button-panel")
       .on('click', 'a:not([class^="title-"]),a:not(".folder")', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var $link = $(this);
       ServerFunctions.getContentAjax($link);
   });
```

Comment: Single-quotes inside single-quotes?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: :).. thanks for the catch. i have modified now.

Answer (score 0):

your html doesnot have anchor element having class `folder`, you can use `.not()`, like

```
$("#content-button-panel > a").not(".folder").on('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var $link = $(this);
     alert($link);
});
```

OR

```
$("#content-button-panel").on('click', 'a:not(.folder)', function (event) {
 ...
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgFgq/6/)
example html

```
<div id="content-button-panel">
    <a href="#" class="title-x">xx</a>
<a href="#" class="title-123243234">yyy</a>
<a href="#" class="title-sadfdsaf folder">zzz</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this to use selectors as

```
$('#content-button-panel, a:not([class*="title-"], [class="folder"])')
       .on('click', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           alert($(this));
       });
```

FIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SptEL/1/)